# Deploy to firebase hosting from multiple computers

Tags: sync, hosting, google-cloud-platform, syncthing

I have two computers synced via syncthing (peer to peer folder sync). In one of them, i have Firebase CLI installed, used for deploying a static website. In the other one, i have all the website files synced. Is it possible to install firebase on the second computer and deploy the same website from there as well?
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Tried again and figured out it was a sync error ‍♂️
Works just fine